# How many $12$ digit even numbers can be formed using $0 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 5 $?

Tags: combinations

It is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3351314/how-many-14-digit-even-numbers-can-be-formed-using-0-1-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4)
The only difference is 12 digits numbers are picked from 14 numbers.

Thanks to many great people, I have understood how to solve the previous question.

However, if I am to pick 12 numbers out of the total 14 numbers, **many new cases emerge** when I having 0, or 2, or 4 in the end there are a different number of them left to be choose, **I cannot just simply remove the repetitive case using division**. What can I do?

Comment: If you truly want to generalize things... I would probably go about this with generating functions or with inclusion-exclusion.  You are correct that simply dividing is not allowable here as we overcounted certain arrangements a potentially different number of times each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $20$ different ways to cross out two digits, namely
$$01,02,03,04,05,11,12,13,14,15,22,23,24,25,33,34,35,44,45,55\ .$$
For each of these solve the old problem, and add up. (The $20$ cases reduce a little by remarking that the problem is symmetric in  $3$ and $5$.)